# SQL Server: Exporting data objects While exporting Database.

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

Say I want to copy a database from one place to another. I can use, e.g.

Insert * From DB1 Into DB2

Where DB2 is the target database. Question: will this insert query also copy all

the data objects: Indexes, triggers, etc.  from DB1 into Db2 ? If not, will

the export Wizard to the job? Anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just backup DB1 (COPY-ONLY) and restore it to DB2?  That is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1):

there is no script that does

```
Insert * From DB1 Into DB2
```

The best way to copy objects is through SQL Server Export Wizard and select all the objects you wan to move.

Also another way is through script each object and run the script in new database.